# Is there a function for showing current date and time?

Tags: excel, datetime, format, excel-2000

I have Microsoft Excel 2000 on my pc. I want to show the current date and time in a cell. I looked in Help and found the `NOW()` function. It does display the current date, but as for the current time, it doesn't show `AM` or `PM`, it shows: `4/19/2011 11:22`. I understand why that is.

Is there some other date/time function that will show AM/PM, or is this something that isn't available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the default is to show the time in 24hr format - so you'll be able to tell am/pm from the hour, but if you want AM/PM to show - right click on the cell and select "Format Cells" and select "Custom Format" - use the following mask - dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM and I think you'll be all good.